# MS SQL Server (ubuntu docker) sqlcmd cannot run the script file

Tags: sql-server, docker, sqlcmd

I use the following command to run the script file on the MS SQL Server.

```
docker exec -it sqlserver /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -d imdb -U sa -P XXX -i data.sql
```

And I get the error

```
Sqlcmd: 'data.sql': Invalid filename.
```

But I can run it with this

```
docker exec -it sqlserver /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -d imdb -U sa -P XXX -Q "the content of data.sql"
```

Does anyone know why I get this error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `data.sql` actually present in the container, or only on the local file system? Keep in mind the whole command is executed in the container, so it won't be able to read any `data.sql` you've got locally unless it's on a shared volume.

Comment: The `-i` switch will reference a file on the container, not your local environment. This means that the file `data.sql` does not exist in the default directory within your container.

Comment: I also try it with the absolute path /home/myname/data.sql. But I get the same error. How to solve this.

Comment: Is `/home/myname/data.sql` on your local environement, or within the docker container?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that is correct. But how to solve it. After I put it inside the docker container, which path I should use here. Thanks.

Comment: If you've made sure the SQL file is built as part of the container, then you must have told it where it will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the error was because the sql script wasn't inside the container so, in order to execute the command above, you can copy the sql script to the container with the following command:

```
docker cp /your/local/path/data.sql sqlserver:/home/
```

This put the file inside the docker instance in the `home` folder. Even you can list the files inside that folder with:

```
docker exec -it sqlserver ls /home
```

And after that you can use the command

```
docker exec -it sqlserver /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -d testdb -U sa -P XXX -i data.sql
```

In my case, I had to add the following SQL command at the top of `data.sql` script:

```
USE testdb
GO
```

That because for some reason it wasn't executing the commands inside the `testdb`.

So I hope it helps you